# How can I load many very large files using uproot?

Tags: uproot

I am using a `CMSSW_11_1_4` environment (Python 3.8.4, uproot 3.11.3, awkward 0.12.20) and I am trying to open a few very large .root files (3 files, 9 GB each) and iterate over some of their branches using an event loop. The code seems to work as expected when iterating over the first file (first 100k events). It takes a lot of time during the first event, but then the rest are processed quickly. That's until it reaches the second file at 100k processed events. Then, the code crashes and an `AssertionError` message is printed out. Here is some code to reproduce the issue given xrootd access.

```py
import uproot
import uproot_methods
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the file and import using uproot
base = 'root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/kdipetri/SUEP/Production_v0.2/2018/NTUP/'
datasets = [
            base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT1000to1500_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root',
            base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT1500to2000_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root',
            base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT2000toInf_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root',
           ]

# Load on lazy arrays
mycache = uproot.ArrayCache("1 GB")
events = uproot.lazyarrays(datasets, 'TreeMaker2/PreSelection', ['HT','CrossSection',
                                                                 'Tracks.fCoordinates.fX',
                                                                 'Tracks.fCoordinates.fY',
                                                                 'Tracks.fCoordinates.fZ',
                                                                 'Tracks_fromPV0',
                                                                 'Tracks_matchedToPFCandidate'],
                                                                 cache=mycache)

trk_multiplicity = np.zeros(events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'].size)
for ievt in range(events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'].size):
    if ievt%1000 == 0:
        print("Processing event %d. Progress: %.2f%%"%(ievt,100*ievt/events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'].size))
    if events['HT'][ievt] < 1200:
        continue
    tracks_x = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'][ievt]
    tracks_y = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fY'][ievt]
    tracks_z = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fZ'][ievt]
    tracks_E = np.sqrt(tracks_x**2+tracks_y**2+tracks_z**2+0.13957**2)
    tracks = uproot_methods.TLorentzVectorArray.from_cartesian(tracks_x, 
                                                               tracks_y, 
                                                               tracks_z, 
                                                               tracks_E)
    tracks_fromPV0 = events['Tracks_fromPV0'][ievt]
    tracks_matchedToPFCandidate = events['Tracks_matchedToPFCandidate'][ievt]
    tracks = tracks[(tracks.pt > 1.) & (tracks.eta < 2.5) & (tracks_fromPV0 >= 2) & 
                    (tracks_matchedToPFCandidate > 0)]
    trk_multiplicity[ievt] = tracks.size

# Plot results
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.gca()

CrossSection = events['CrossSection'][events['HT'] > 1200]
trk_multiplicity = trk_multiplicity[events['HT'] > 1200]

ax.hist(trk_multiplicity, bins=100, density=True, weights=CrossSection, histtype='step')

plt.show()
```

I am convinced that this is some memory issue because I have managed to process multiple files (though much smaller and locally stored) this way. How can I overcome this? Do I need to handle caching in a different way?

**Edit (10/28/2020):** I tried switching to uproot4(0.0.27)/awkward1(0.3.1) without much success. I converted the same code to the following:

```py
import uproot4 as uproot
import uproot_methods
import awkward1 as ak
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the file and import using uproot
base = 'root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/kdipetri/SUEP/Production_v0.2/2018/NTUP/'
datasets = {
    base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT1000to1500_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root': 'TreeMaker2/PreSelection',
    base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT1500to2000_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root': 'TreeMaker2/PreSelection',
    base + 'Autumn18.QCD_HT2000toInf_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root': 'TreeMaker2/PreSelection',
}


# Load on lazy arrays
events = uproot.lazy(datasets)

trk_multiplicity = np.zeros(len(events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX']))
for ievt in range(len(events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'])):
    if ievt%1000 == 0:
        print("Processing event %d. Progress: %.2f%%"%(ievt,100*ievt/len(events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'])))
    if events['HT'][ievt] < 1200:
        continue
    tracks_x = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'][ievt]
    tracks_y = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fY'][ievt]
    tracks_z = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fZ'][ievt]
    tracks_E = np.sqrt(tracks_x**2+tracks_y**2+tracks_z**2+0.13957**2)
    tracks = uproot_methods.TLorentzVectorArray.from_cartesian(ak.to_awkward0(tracks_x),ak.to_awkward0(tracks_y),ak.to_awkward0(tracks_z),ak.to_awkward0(tracks_E))
    tracks_fromPV0 = events['Tracks_fromPV0'][ievt]
    tracks_matchedToPFCandidate = events['Tracks_matchedToPFCandidate'][ievt]
    tracks = tracks[(tracks.pt > 1.) & (tracks.eta < 2.5) & (ak.to_awkward0(tracks_fromPV0) >= 2) & 
                    (ak.to_awkward0(tracks_matchedToPFCandidate) > 0)]
    trk_multiplicity[ievt] = tracks.size

# Plot results
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.gca()

CrossSection = events['CrossSection'][events['HT'] > 1200]
trk_multiplicity = trk_multiplicity[events['HT'] > 1200]

ax.hist(trk_multiplicity, bins=100, density=True, weights=CrossSection, histtype='step')

plt.show()
```

This time the code begun processing the events immediately though quite a bit slower (probably the smaller cache?). Again, when it reached the second file, the code crashed this time with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/plotEventShapes_lazy.py", line 43, in <module>
    tracks_x = events['Tracks.fCoordinates.fX'][ievt]
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward1/highlevel.py", line 974, in __getitem__
    self._layout[where], self._behavior, cache=self._cache
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward1/partition.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    return PartitionedArray.from_ext(self._ext.getitem_at(where))
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/behaviors/TBranch.py", line 2017, in array
    _ranges_or_baskets_to_arrays(
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/behaviors/TBranch.py", line 3264, in _ranges_or_baskets_to_arrays
    uproot4.source.futures.delayed_raise(*obj)
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/source/futures.py", line 46, in delayed_raise
    raise exception_value.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/behaviors/TBranch.py", line 3189, in chunk_to_basket
    basket = uproot4.models.TBasket.Model_TBasket.read(
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/model.py", line 730, in read
    self.read_members(chunk, cursor, context, file)
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/models/TBasket.py", line 230, in read_members
    ) = cursor.fields(chunk, _tbasket_format2, context)
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/source/cursor.py", line 195, in fields
    return format.unpack(chunk.get(start, stop, self, context))
  File "/uscms/home/chpapage/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot4/source/chunk.py", line 370, in get
    raise uproot4.deserialization.DeserializationError(
uproot4.deserialization.DeserializationError: while reading

    TBasket version None as uproot4.models.TBasket.Model_TBasket (? bytes)
        fNbytes: -1607368158
        fObjlen: -1243566277
        fDatime: 2634931141
        fKeylen: -27664
        fCycle: 21409

attempting to get bytes 483015:483033
outside expected range 510698:538758 for this Chunk
in file root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/kdipetri/SUEP/Production_v0.2/2018/NTUP/Autumn18.QCD_HT1500to2000_TuneCP5_13TeV-madgraphMLM-pythia8_RA2AnalysisTree.root
```

One last comment, I ran the same code with much smaller files (the signal files that are about 1 GB each) but this time with xrootd access and the loop finished with no issues. Could this be a caching issue because of the very large filesize?

Comment: I think the key indication is when you said "xrootd". If it's possible, could you try testing this on local files or Uproot 4? Uproot 3 reads remote files in an inefficient way: it may be reading too much. Note that Uproot 4 returns Awkward 1 arrays, which won't work with `uproot_methods.TLorentzVectorArray`, but there's an `ak.to_awkward0` function in Awkward 1.

Comment: @JimPivarski I have tried this for local files and it was working without any issues. The files were a lot smaller, though. (About 1GB each.) I will try with uproot4 and I will post the results. Thanks!

Comment: @JimPivarski I have appended to the main body information about me trying this with uproot4. A small summary: the code failed again to change file but this time it produced a more informative error message. This seems to happen only for huge files even with xrootd access.

Comment: The difference in performance that you see is likely due to the differences in how Uproot 4 gathers chunks of data: it started right away but was slower because it's streaming better. You're definitely running into a deserialization error: those numbers for the TBasket parameters are junk, likely reading at the wrong byte position. Cache only affects performance, so we can't blame it on cache unless there's a bug and this doesn't look like a cache-related bug. Your successful file was 1 GB; it could be ROOT's handling of 32-bit vs 64-bit, where the threshold is 4 GB.

Comment: If you can get a > 4 GB file (safely large enough, like 6 GB) and you see it fail when accessed locally (not through XRootD), could you please post it as a bug report on GitHub? You're testing an extreme that I previously haven't been able to test. If you don't have disk space to test a file locally, then just pass the 6 GB file to me anyway and I'll test it. If the data are private, you can send a link to my GMail address: "jpivarski" (using Dropbox, CERNBox, or whatever is convenient). But do make it a GitHub Issue so that I don't forget about it. Thanks!

Comment: @JimPivarski I think that I can test it locally. I will keep you updated!

Comment: For anyone who wants to follow this, there is now an open issue: https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot4/issues/131